# android access point/hot spot doubt

Tags: android, wifi, access-point

I am building an app which requires an access point to be enabled throughout... how can i get an interrupt or notification whenever the access point gets disabled...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a WIFI connection or any connection at all? This will trigger when wifi drops:
[SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)

Comment: i need to know when the access point that has been created by me gets disabled ...there are cases when access points gets disabled after a certain time of inactivity to save batttery...how to detect this programmatically ??